# Error while using click module in python - Error: No such option: --addtask

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Error - Error: No such option: --addtask

I ran code using - python3 main.py --addtask task

On running this addtask function should execute but it isnt

Saw several youtube videos still couldnt fix it
Pls help!
code below

Code -

````
import click
import json
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()
filename = './db.json'
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass
def veiw_data():
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        temp = json.load(f)
        for entry in temp:
            print(entry)
def get_data(name:str):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        temp = json.load(f)
        for entry in temp:
            if entry['name'] == name:
                return entry
def insert_data(data:dict):
    with open (filename, 'r') as f:
        temp = json.loads(f)
        print(temp)
    temp.append(data)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(temp,f,indent = 4)
def delete_data(name:str):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        temp = json.loads(f)
        i = 0
        for entry in temp:
            if entry[name]  == name:
                temp.pop(i)
            i+=1
                     
@click.command()
@click.option('--addtask',help='Add a task')
def addtask(task):
    data = {
            "name":task
            }   
    insert_data(data)
    console.print(f'[bold cyan]Task Added -[/bold cyan] [red]{task}[/red]')


cli.add_command(addtask)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

try this rename click with cli an remove the line : cli.add_command(addtask)

@cli.command()
@cli.option('--addtask',help='Add a task')
def addtask(task):
data = {
"name":task
}
insert_data(data)
console.print(f'[bold cyan]Task Added -[/bold cyan] [red]{task}[/red]')

Comment: Got error - 
 @cli.option('--addtask',help='Add a task')
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'option'